# IndexError: list index out of range in react pane

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I'm making a react pane like Facebook which is working fine but when I am trying to update the react it causing an exception like `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"`

**Update:**
Since the debugging has continued, I made some progress and this is the 3rd edit. Now I fixed the previous error and fixed 8 issues there.

In my `views.py` there is a new error `react_type = [emoji_tuple[0] for emoji_tuple in React.choices if emoji_tuple[1] == body['emoji']][0] IndexError: list index out of range`

Here is my `models.py` >>>

```
class React(models.Model):
    
    choices = [
        (1, "like"),
        (2, "dislike"),
        (3, "smile"),
        (4, "heart"),
        (5, "thanks")
    ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="reacted by")
    post = models.ForeignKey(UpPost, related_name="react", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name="react", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    react_type = models.IntegerField(choices=choices, default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "react"
        verbose_name_plural = "reacts"
        unique_together = [["user", "post"], ["user", "comment"]]
        ordering = ["react_type"]
    def __str__(self):
        elem = self.post if (self.post is not None) else self.comment
        return f"React {self.id} by {self.user} on object {elem}"
```

One of my concepts is I might put a check in `elif request.method == "POST":` this block when if there is no react do something. But exactly what to do isn't clear to me.

this is my new `views.py` >>>

```
@login_required
def react(request, act, actId):
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            if act == "post":
                post = UpPost.objects.get(pk=actId)
                react_obj = React.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post)
            elif act == "comment":
                comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=actId)
                react_obj = React.objects.filter(user=request.user, comment=comment)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error":_("Action not justified. You can not react anything except post or comment!")}, status=400)
        except ( UpPost.DoesNotExist, Comment.DoesNotExist ):
            return JsonResponse({"error":_("Post or comment may have deleted or removed")}, status=404)
        else:
            if len(react_obj) != 1:
                return JsonResponse({})
            react_obj = react_obj[0]
            return JsonResponse({"react":"True", "emoji": [emoji_tuple[1] for emoji_tuple in React.choices if emoji_tuple[0] == react_obj.react_type][0]}, status=200)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        body = json.loads(request.body)
        react_type = [emoji_tuple[0] for emoji_tuple in React.choices if emoji_tuple[1] == body['emoji']][0]
        try:
            if act == "post":
                post = UpPost.objects.get(pk=actId)
                react = React.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post)
                if react:
                    react.delete()
                react_obj = React(user=request.user, post=post, react_type=react_type)
            elif act == "comment":
                comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=actId)
                react = React.objects.filter(user=request.user, comment=comment)
                if react:
                    react.delete()
                react_obj = React(user=request.user, comment=comment, react_type=react_type)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error":_("Action not justified. You can not react anything except post or comment")}, status=400)
        except ( UpPost.DoesNotExist, Comment.DoesNotExist ):
            return JsonResponse({"error":_("Post or comment may have deleted")}, status=404)
        react_obj.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=201)
    elif request.method == "PUT":
        body = json.loads(request.body)
        react_num = [emoji_tuple[0] for emoji_tuple in React.choices if emoji_tuple[1] == body['emoji']][0]
        try:
            if act == "post":
                post = UpPost.objects.get(pk=actId)
                old = React.objects.get(user=request.user, post=post)
            elif act == "comment":
                comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=actId)
                old = React.objects.get(user=request.user, comment=comment)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error":_("Action not justified. You can not react anything except post or comment.")}, status= 400)
        except ( UpPost.DoesNotExist, Comment.DoesNotExist ):
            return JsonResponse({"error":_("Post or comment may have deleted")}, status=404)
        if old.react_type != react_num:
            old.react_type = react_num
            old.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=201)
```

what is that I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try simplifying your code, by expanding the list comprehensions, and breaking your one function into multiple functions. Its just too dense and compact to debug effectively. You need to simplify the code a bit (and check your indentations).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thank you, sir. I'm working on it.