# In Django template button is not working as expected

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

In my project, I used the function toggle_follow which is working fine but in my template on the first click nothing changed in the second click it turns to unfollow as expected, and after again clicking it becomes to follow which is also expected. After that, it doesn't work. Though the follow shows in the following tab and update the list but the button stopped working.

The problem is, the follow counter is not updating properly and not storing into database as If I follow someone and another user visit the same profile, the user by default see that he is following the user also whom I'm following which is not as expected.

However, for first three time the result is expected and working properly.

my models.py >>>

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follow")
    followed = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followers")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "following"
        verbose_name_plural = "followings"
        unique_together = ["user", "followed"]
    def str(self):
        return f"{self.user} is following {self.followed}"
    def followed_post(self):
        return self.followed.posts.order_by("-date").all()
```

my views.py >>>

```
@login_required
def toggle_follow(request, id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return HttpResponse(status=405)
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            follow_obj = Follow.objects.get(user=request.user.id, followed=id)
        except Follow.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                to_follow = User.objects.get(pk=id)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return HttpResponse(status=404)
            else:
                new_follow_obj = Follow(user=request.user, followed = to_follow)
                new_follow_obj.save()
        else:
            follow_obj.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("profile", args=[id]))

@login_required
def profile(request, id):
    data = User.objects.get(pk=id)
    posts = data.posts.order_by("-date").all()
    followingId = Follow.objects.filter(user=id).values_list('followed',flat=True)
    followersId = Follow.objects.filter(followed=id).values_list('id',flat=True)
    followingUser = User.objects.filter(id__in = followingId)
    followersUser = User.objects.filter(id__in = followersId)
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
    page_num = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_num)
    return render(request, "network/profile.html", {"data": data, "following": followingUser, "followerss": followersUser, "page_obj": page_obj, "comment":ProcComment(auto_id=False)})
```

my template >>>

```
<div class="profile-username">
            {{ data.username }}
        </div>
        <div class="profile-buttons">
            {% if user.id != data.id %}
                <form action="{% url 'toggle_follow' id=data.id %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                {% if user in followerss %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger unfollow">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-person-x-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%3E
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H1zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm6.146-2.854a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L14 6.293l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L14.707 7l1.147 1.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L14 7.707l-1.146 1.147a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L13.293 7l-1.147-1.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
                            </svg>
                            {% trans "Unfollow" %}
                        </button>
                {% else %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success follow">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-person-plus-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%3E
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H1zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm7.5-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V7h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8h-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H13V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                            </svg>
                            {% trans "Follow" %}
                        </button>
                {% endif %}
```

I have been stuck for more than a week. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure you are calculating `followersId` incorrectly, you are getting `Follow` ids but I think you want `User` ids? Try changing the values_list to `.values_list('user', flat=True)`?

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you so much. It worked. I just missed the logic over and over again and focused on models for the solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IainShelvington will you like to go through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904128/integrityerror-unique-constraint-failed)? I think you can solve the issue as you solved one of the problems of the same project. Thanks.